# Evaluating only one column of a $m \times m$ matrix without evaluating the matrix itself

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have

```
f[x_] := SparseArray[{someRules}, {m, m}];
g[x_] := MatrixPower[f[x], k];
```

Would it be possible to evaluate *only* the $n$-th column ($n\neq m$) of `g` without evaluating the whole thing?

Would a simple `a = g[x'][[n]]` work? Or should I define `f` and `g` differently?

**EDIT**: I just noticed I wrote the above expression for a row, not a column, so the correct expression would be `a = g[x'][[All, 1]]`. Just a defect of form, of course; the problem still is the same.

Comment: `a = g[x'][[n]]` certainly *will not* work. It is an interesting question and a difficult problem. I'm inclined to say it is not possible, unless your columns all happen to be linearly independent, but hopefully I will be proved wrong.

Comment: @Oleksandr Why will it certainly not work? For me I get a `SparseArray` output anyway, which is a slight suggestion that it hasn't normalised anything.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wouldn't be that easy.
But, as I'm working with very large matrices (sparse, but still large), I tend to be optimist!

Comment: @PatrickStevens to form a matrix power requires a matrix decomposition (e.g. SVD), does it not? And this operation depends on the whole matrix, not just one column. I interpret the question as asking how we can avoid doing calculations that affect only values not lying in this column.

Comment: @Oleksandr I see what you mean - my bad. Interesting question indeed.

Comment: Never use `N` as a variable, since it is a *Mathematica* function (give numerical value).  It is also good practice to avoid *all* upper-case letters for variables, such as your `K`.  Also do not use upper-case for named terms, such as `Rules`, since it may conflict with the thousands of *Mathematica* function names (such as the close `Rule`).  Don't even do it as an "example," as others will cut-and-paste your code.  Get into good coding habits!  You could very very easily use `myRules`, `n`, and `k` here, no matter how complicated your own terms were.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I know, that is just an example: as you can see, I didn't even write the rules in the sparse matrix. My variables, alas, have way more complicated names...

Comment: Ok, I changed the variable names.

Comment: Have you tried just working out the indexed form of the product of a matrix K times? That seems like the most straightforward way. Wikipedia even has the sums worked out on the Matrix Multiplication page, you'd just need to translate it to MMA.

Comment: @N.J.Evans yes, I could, but I'd still need every element of the original `f` matrix, which takes me back to the problem.

Comment: Based on some simple testing the general result depends on the entire `f` matrix, so there is no way around that.  (Of course if there is some specific structure to the sparse array that might change things )

Comment: What about using `a = g[x].vec` where `vec` is a sparse array with a $1$ on the $n$-th position?
I'm guessing this would be way slower...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `MatrixPower[]` indicates that you can take the *action* of a matrix power on a given vector. In particular, to get a single column of a matrix power, you thus need the action of the matrix power on an appropriate unit vector.

For instance,

```
n = 6;
mat = SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j + k == n + 1 :> 1, {k_, k_} :> 1}, {n, n}];

m = 4; (* power *) k = 3; (* column *)
MatrixPower[mat, m, UnitVector[n, k]]
   {0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0}

mp = MatrixPower[mat, m];
mp[[All, k]]
   {0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0}
```

`MatrixExp[]` also admits an "action" form.

Comment: I didn't know about this. Does this speed up the process?

Comment: Assuming that they implemented it properly under the hood, yes. Actions of matrix functions are an active area of research, it should be said.

Comment: Alright. What if now, instead of `MatrixPower`, I wanted to do multiplications between matrices? They all have the same structure. For example, I'd like to do

`a := Table[{RandomChoice[{i, j}], ... , RandomChoice[{k, l}]}, {n}]` (where `a` is set delayed) so I'd want the k-th column of `b=a.a.a ... .a` 
Is this possible, or should I just take the column, now?

Comment: I don't know if there's a more efficient way than just multiplying the matrices in sequence to a unit vector.

Comment: 31 hours reduced to just 40 minutes... I'd say that's an improvement!

Thank you so much.